# how to do a cloud function firebase importing data from Bucket to database realtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I tried with this code but it's not working,
I need  do a cloud function firebase importing data from Bucket to database realtime

```
exports.getbackups = functions.runWith({ memory: "128MB", timeoutSeconds: 60, }).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      res = FirebaseServices.setHeaders(res);
      let send = await FirebaseServices.verifyIdToken(req);
      var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    
        const url = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/report-transfer-data/2022-08-01T11%3A12%3A57Z_sp200200011002-report_data.json.gz?authuser=1'
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = (event) => {
          const blob = xhr.response;
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    
        const baseReport = document.getElementById('baseReport');
        baseReport.setAttribute('src', url);
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Cloud Function you need to interact with the Cloud Storage service via the Admin SDK.

In particular, you'll find in the [SDK Reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/index.html) an example on how to [download the file into CF memory](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download-examples) and then you can use its content to write to the RTDB.

Something along the following lines:

```
exports.getbackups = functions.runWith({ memory: "128MB", timeoutSeconds: 60, }).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    
    const filePath = ...;  // file path in Cloud Storage without the gs://
    
    const file = admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .file(filepath);
    
    const downloadResponse = await file.download();
    const contents = downloadResponse[0];
    
    // Do what you want with contents
    
    res.send(....);  // Terminate the HTTPS Cloud Function
    // Correctly terminating your CF is important. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions
    // and in particular the embedded videos
  
  });
```

Comment: thank you  but i need a function to confert file from gzip to json

Comment: Any JS library that does what you want can be used in your Cloud Function